# hostname incorrect in sysprocesses

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

I'm running SQL Server 2000. While doing some profiling to trace activity, I noticed some hostnames showing up that were mysterious -- names that shouldn't exist on the network anymore. I got the MAC address for one of them from master.dbo.sysprocesses, looked up the IP address in the ARP cache, and then used nbtstat to resolve that IP to a network name. The name it resolved to was not the name in sysprocesses, nor was the name in sysprocesses resolvable on the network.

So where is this name coming from? Does SQL Server have a hostname cache somewhere that needs to be cleared? How can I fix this so that the correct network hostname shows in my traces?

Comment: This is pretty common when dealing with Access and Excel connecting to the SQL Server, as the ComputerName which is passed in by default is the name of the machine which the file was first created on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is set by the client.

It is passed in via the ["Workstation ID"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130822.aspx) property in the connection string. So I presume that you will need to make some configuration updates on your client machines.